# How to archive large folders when the space available is limited

Tags: perl, compression, zip, archive

I am trying to compress a folder and create a zip file.
The size of the folder is nearly 75 GB and the total disk space is 100 GB.
So,when I am trying to use common zipping utilities like 7z or Peazip,they are running out of space.

Is there a way/software which deletes the original file as soon as it is archived - so that I don't run out of space.

I can write a bit of perl code using Archive::zip but not sure if that is the best method.

Please advice.

Comment: Most compression programs write information at the end, and in the event of an error want to be able to recover.  If you're on a platform with GNU tar you could use that (along with -z) and --remove-files to remove files as they are added to the archive.

Comment: Can you really not afford $60 or so for a new 1TB disk drive?

Answer (score 1):

You can repeatedly use the 'move' command of the ZIP (switch -m) to add individual files to the existing zip archive.

```
zip -m /path/to/zipfile.zip file1 file2 file3
```

Answer (score 0):

Compress the individual files first, THEN create the zipfile.

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the input into multiple chunks, each one 10 GB or so, and compress them individually. Most compression tools will anyway not benefit from a very large input.